# Background для ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

У меня есть `ListView` и у него есть `Header` и `Footer`. Их разметки в `CardView`. А в `Content` список, у которых должен быть один `background`.
Вот картинка где наглядно видно:
У меня сейчас вот как получается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И как нужно сделать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли так реализовать в ListView? если да то как, если нет то как реализовать?

Comment: А нужен ли тут listview? Или если проскроллить то покажет другого пассажира?

Comment: Нет! не покажет... увеличивается только маршрут

Comment: ну так если скролиться только маршрут, зачем все засовывать в listview? как по мне, так тут 3 контейнера, первый и последний прибиты к верху и низу соответственно, средний на всю длинну, и как раз он содержит в себе listview

Comment: Мне нужно все 3 контейнера скролились... а не только маршрут!

Comment: Я делал так, `ScrollView` > первый контейнер > второй контейнер с `listView` > третий контейнер. Но к сожалению в низу 2 контейнера был огромное пустое пространство!